# How to limit the rows and columns of ShowGridLines in WPF Grid?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

How to limit the rows and columns of ShowGridLines in WPF Grid?

By default, ShowGridLines will be applied to all rows and columns, is there any way to set the rows and columns that ShowGridLines is effective?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible, the ShowGridLines feature is pretty basic and only an on/off switch.

You could consider breaking up into multiple Grid objects where not all show them.